# How to iterate through pandas data frame that meet some condition and append those rows to new data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, append

I'm trying to create a function (get_filtered_df) that given a filter and a dataset, iterates through a specific column and applies some function (get_filter) that looks for rows that meet those conditions and get added to some final data frame.

This is what I've accomplished so far:

```
def get_filter(filter):
    string_container = []
    
    string_container.append(filter.upper())
    string_container.append(filter.lower())
    # More conditions here
    
    return (string_container)

def get_filtered_df(string_container, df):
    filtered_df = pd.DataFrame(df[df['Titles'].str.contains(string_container[0])], columns=df.columns)
    
    return(filtered_df)
```

The problem comes when instead of a fixed index (0) I try to iterate using a for or while loop as I never get the function to append the rows that are meeting the conditions.

This is the specific instruction that I tried to use:

```
for i in range len(get_filter('star')):
    filtered_df.append(df[df['Title'].str.contains(get_filter('star')[i])])
```

filtered_df returns always empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pd.DataFrame.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) method returns a new object. In your code, you are appending a new Dataframe - which is lost at each iteration, hence returning an empty DataFrame.

You need to update `filtered_df` in your loop in order to update `filtered_df`:

```
def get_filtered_df(string_container, df):
    filtered_df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=df.columns)
    for i in range(len(string_container)):
        filtered_df = filtered_df.append(df[df['Titles'].str.contains(string_container[i])], ignore_index=True)
    return(filtered_df)
```

should work.